# Adding new feature class to already classified image in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, envi, land-classification

I have at hand this already classified image with 8 vegetation classes.  Now I would want to change a part of existing vegetation class to a NEW vegetation class, making it 9 classes.

I do not want to reclassify the image as it will take some time.  Also, I just needed to change few polygons for the 9th class.

How can I do this?

Is there a way to change the class manually?

I have ENVI 5.2 and ArcMap 10.2.

This is a portion of the original image with 8 classes:

[image]

This is a portion of the new 9th class:

[image]

This is how I want it to be (In here, as just did an overlay for visualization purposes. Can the CON tool add the new class 9 to the original image?)

[image]

When I applied CON, the output was this, which was just the same as the 9th class.

[image]

---

Finally, with help from @MichaelMiles-Stimson, the merging works.  A new class 9 was added to an already classified image with 8 classes by doing this in the Raster Calculator: Con(IsNull("rip_raster"),"classif9.dat",9)

Comment: Do the values exist in the raster but just need to be added to the RAT? I would think that if you wanted to insert new values into an existing raster that doesn't already exist a tool like CON would be able to do that fairly easily (requires Spatial Analyst license).

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thanks for the reply.  The original classification is in raster format, the classes were numbered 1 to 8.  Now, I would insert a new class, number 9. How can I use CON? I have not tried this tool yet.  Can you guide me with it?  I will appreciate any help.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can either use Con tool or Raster Calculator tool, you enter a query expression and then supply a true and false statement.. something like Con ("Original_Raster.tif" == Value, 9,Classified_Raster.tif) where Value is the number from the original raster that you want to become 9 in the classified raster. If you could include a screen shot of the original and classified rasters (with legend) I could probably be more specific.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Sorry, I do not know how to attached the screenshot.  Let me just put it this way: the original raster has 8 classes:  Agriculture 1, Agriculture 2, Agriculture 3, Agriculture 4, Agriculture 5, Agriculture 6, Agriculture 7, Agriculture 8.  I now have a raster (tif) of the new class Agriculture 9.  This Agriculture 9 class will be inserted into the original raster.  As I look at it, some parts of the areas of Agriculture 4, Agriculture 5, and Agriculture 6 will have to change and become Agriculture 9.   Will CON solve this problem?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Con](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm) (spatial analyst) you specify a query, in this case NewRaster == 9 and it will populate the output (new) raster where the update raster is 9 with the true value (9) and the values of the old classifed raster where it is not:

[image]

Or using [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm):

[image]

Please look at environments [Cell Size](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Cell_Size/001w0000001s000000/) and [Snap Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000000m000000) to help align the pixels.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I will try this and I will update you later.

Comment: Hi Michael.  I had a CON failed process.  But i think I know what caused it.  This is a very simple question.  How can I change the cell value of a class in a raster attribute table?  

OID, Value, Count
0, 0, 38000

I want to change the 'Value ' from 0 to 2.  How will I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Use field calculator. The RAT (Raster Attribute Table) is just another table. Open in ArcMap, open the attribute table of the raster, select the row 0 and right click up the top to access field calculator, type in 2 (no quotes) and hit ok. Be careful what you do though, that does not change the value in the raster just the table that interprets it; If there already is a row with value 2 in the table you will have a duplicate entry, if the value 2 does not appear in the raster the row will now point to something else. After doing this you will need to calculate statistics to restore the count.

Comment: Did you get any error message when the Con failed?

Comment: Hi Michael. I ran CON and it failed:

"An invalid SQL statement was used.An invalid SQL statement was used.Failed to execute (Con).Failed at Tue Sep 15 17:26:05 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.10 seconds)"  I wanted to attach screenshot but I wonder why each time I send my reply, http://gis.stackexchange.com will ask me to login.  But it never logged me in!

Comment: What was the *exact* syntax of the statement you used in Con? Perhaps I have made a mistake with the Con tool... It looks like it wants = instead of == for equality. Did you try the Raster Calculator method? I prefer Raster Calculator as the statements are easier to control.

Comment: That looks like the syntax error... in the Con tool Value = 9 is correct (not Value == 9) but in Raster Calculator the syntax requires the == i.e. Con("full_path_to_raster" == 9,9,"full_path_to_other_Raster"). I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, so I tried both methods and both came out the same results.  However, the result is not the one I want. Instead of the giving me the original extent (but this time with a new 9th class), it gave me the new class as the output.  Meaning, the result was just the same as the input "update" raster.  Here is what I placed on the Raster Calculator: Con("rip_raster" == 9,9,"classif9.dat").  "rip_raster" is the raster of the new class 9, while "classif9.dat" is the original raster with 8 classes.  Is there something wrong with what I've done?  Thanks again.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a picture of the same area in both with legend please, zoomed in enough to see individual pixels, I am struggling to visualize what it is that you're after.

Comment: I just edited the question with screenshots. Thank you for your time Michael.

Comment: So what did you get from Con? The process as described should have done that - output raster is 9 where 9th class is 9 and the same as the original class where it is not.

Comment: I added a sample screenshot of the result using both methods.  The "new 9th class" raster has this table: VALUE: 9 and COUNT: 5000.  The same columns of VALUE and COUNT are found in the original 8-class raster.

Comment: Is there a projection difference between the two rasters? Does ArcGis read "classif9.dat", perhaps change it to an Esri GRID, GeoTiff or ERDAS img format... Con is supposed to use the values in the raster where the statement is false ("rip_raster" == 9 is false)... it could also be NoData handling, does the rip_raster have 9 and NoData values only? If so we can change the statement around but only in Raster Calculator. Con(IsNull("rip_raster"),"classif9.dat",9)

Comment: Hi Mike!  It worked.  Thank you very much.  Con(IsNull("rip_raster"),"classif9.dat",9) is the savior! I updated the question above with the solution to the problem.  One more question if you don't mind:  Is there a way to change misclassified cells?  Like changing from class 2 to class 3?  There's this ARIS GRID Editor for ArcMap that could somehow do this, but it is pricey.  Is CON applicable with this type of problem too?  Thanks again!

Comment: Save as type tiff (make sure you get a world file) and paint in with GIMP or PhotoShop, **beware** both of these will remove georeference on save, you **need** the world file to keep the spatial information. There is ArcScan which may be able to do it, but it's pricey too. I don't know about ENVI, I'm still waiting to trial that software. I wrote a C# tool to adjust single pixels in ArcMap because I couldn't find a satisfactory way to interactively modify one pixel at a time, that doesn't mean there isn't one, just I didn't find it.